# Mounted a disk, mount showing but disk unused

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

I mounted 2 disks. This is the output of "df" for these drives:

```
/dev/sdb1      1921802432     77852 1824032524   1% /sftpuser/backups/2
/dev/sdc1      1921802432     77852 1824032524   1% /sftpuser/backups/1
```

but all data (roughly 400GB) saved to /sftpuser/backups/1 and /2 isn´t saved on either of these but the main harddrive (which is completly full, even though it has only the base install and a few docker-container):

```
root@dockerserver:/home/sftpuser/backups/1# df MeineDaten/
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      460438568 437135372         0 100% /
```

Here is my /etc/fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/e37af8bd-6404-4892-bf4d-bbe56581d981 / ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
UUID=859b995d-2562-4439-bb1a-65e62cd88b77 /sftpuser/backups/1    ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       2
UUID=d873bfb7-7329-44bc-973d-2a290f929648 /sftpuser/backups/2    ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       2
```

I am using Ubuntu Server 20.04.

Can anyone tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: What from your output should indicate the data were not saved to the correct destination? What is the command you used to save? Is it correctly pointing to the correct destination? Partitions appear to be mounted correctly, so copying or moving data there should go well if there is no error message indicating otherwise.

Comment: In /backups/1 and /2 are 400GB of data but as the first df command shows is that sdb1 and sdc1 are both empty and sda2 is full even though there should only be the base install plus some docker-containers on there. And the second df command shows that it´s on the main drive (sda1) that even though it´s saved under the mounting point: /sftpuser/backups/1  i.e.  on sdc1.

Comment: Did you create the /sftpuser/backups/1 and /2 mount points? Maybe not, and your backups just got created on sda1/sda2... hence your disk is now full.

Comment: From my knowledge the two last lines in /etc/fstab create the mount points, or am i wrong?

Comment: No, you have to manually create the mount points. Since you didn't, your backups went to existing directories on your primary HDD/SSD. You'll want to discover them and then delete them to recover the space. If these are backup drives, you'd probably want to mount them on /mnt or /media, not user-specific.

Comment: How do i create mount points? I thought you only have to create an empty folder on your main drive and then use /etc/fstab like i did and point to that folder, what step am i missing.

Comment: `sudo mkdir /media/backup1`, etc. and change your /etc/fstab. (Understand that root will own them). You also should change your sda2 mount in /etc/fstab to `UUID=e37af8bd-6404-4892-bf4d-bbe56581d981 / ext4 defaults 0 0`

Comment: So i have to mount a drive under /media/ and cant mount it under a specifc home-directory?? But then i cant use my current sftp setup, because it can only access everthing under /home/sftpuser.

Comment: You can, but then only sftpuser can access them (with default privs set up in /etc/fstab). You'll have to make sure that root doesn't own them.

Comment: But then i didn´t do anything wrong with my setup, right? In my setup i did "mkdir /backups/1" and then made the corresponding /etc/fstab entry. And the same with /backups/2 for the second disk. And the "problem" that only sftpuser can write isn´t really a problem if thats the user used for sftp.

Comment: `mkdir /backups/1` created those mount points at the root of your HDD. If you want them user-specific you'll have to do `mkdir /home/sftpuser/backups/1` and /2. Same in /etc/fstab.

Comment: So my problem is in /etc/fstab, that instead of "/sftpuser/backups/1" i have to write "/home/sftpuser/backups/1" ?

Comment: But you also have to create the mount points there, not at the root of your HDD.

Comment: The directories are already there as you can see in the second "df" command, as i am already in the directory

Comment: No, the mount points don't get created on sdb1 and sdc1. They get created in /mnt or /media or in /home/sftpuser.

Comment: Then how do i create the mount points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Create the user-specific mount points:

```
mkdir /home/sftpuser/backups/1
mkdir /home/sftpuser/backups/2
```

/etc/fstab:

```
UUID=859b995d-2562-4439-bb1a-65e62cd88b77 /home/sftpuser/backups/1    ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       2
UUID=d873bfb7-7329-44bc-973d-2a290f929648 /home/sftpuser/backups/2    ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       2
```

Note: see `man fstab` for more information.

Note: remember to locate your old backup files at /sftpuser/backups and delete them to regain your disk space.

Comment: I will try that. One more question: Is there a difference between a folder and a mountpoint?

Comment: No. Technically probably the same... except for ownership and privs.

Comment: I will choose your answer as correct, but my problem is sadly not completly solved. I think its an underlying problem with the drives, because on one reboot they were correctly mounted and there was no data except a lost+found(probably because the data from the main drive that was there was now not correctly linked) with my old/unchanged setup. After another reboot they were again not correctly mounted but the data was back.

Comment: @Knniff  Your "old" data is sitting in /sftpuser/backups/1 and /2. This should either be copied to the drives at their current mount points, and/or deleted (to regain disk space on sdaX), and then created fresh on the external drives. I don't know what your sftp backup/download/scripts are doing.

Comment: @Knniff You could unmount the external drives, and `fsck` them to check if they're ok. `fsck -f /dev/sdb1`, etc.

Comment: Yes, i will do that, thank you.